# Why 2nd layer of image attached to 1st in Gimp?

Tags: gimp

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJAo9.jpg)

Questions:

1. How to edit monitor screen layer separately, which is attached to 1st layer
2. If I tried edit the monitor screen individually background size is fixed so I can make the monitor screen size larger, so how to fix that too?

Comment: If my information is not sufficient. Pls let me know how to contact you

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do [with programming](/help/on-topic)?

Comment: Did you intend to post this on [superuser](https://superuser.com)?

Comment: then my theres separate category for gimp or photoshop etc

Comment: @Kamalesh There could be programming related questions to GIMP or Photoshop.